# How to tell if razor is running?

Tags: debian, spamassassin, spam-filter, amavis, razor

I have a mailserver which is using amavis to do the spam testing (through spamassassin). Now I wanted to use razor and pyzor as well.

I installed them and did the following:

```
# su - amavis -s /bin/bash 
# razor-admin -create 
# razor-admin -register 
# pyzor discover
```

As it is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew#Spamassassin

Now my question: How do i figure out if razor and pyzor are running? I don't see anything in the mail.log and don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`spamassassin`](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.3.x/doc/spamassassin-run.html) binary in debug mode.

Taken from this SpamAssassin Wiki: [Using Pyzor](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/UsingPyzor)

```
echo "test" | spamassassin -D pyzor 2>&1 | less
```

or

```
spamassassin -t -D 2>&1 < /tmp/myspam| less
```

First command was send string "test" to spamassassin. The second one, send full source of email in `/tmp/myspam` to spamasssassin.

This test should return output similar to:

```
...
Oct  6 11:11:46.956 [10904] dbg: pyzor: network tests on, attempting Pyzor
Oct  6 11:11:52.055 [10904] dbg: pyzor: pyzor is available: /bin/pyzor
Oct  6 11:11:52.056 [10904] dbg: pyzor: opening pipe: /bin/pyzor --homedir /some/dir/.pyzor check < /tmp/.spamassassin10904BmyCb9tmp
Oct  6 11:11:52.344 [10904] dbg: pyzor: [10906] finished: exit 1
Oct  6 11:11:52.345 [10904] dbg: pyzor: check failed: no response
...
```

or

```
...
Oct  6 19:34:05.896 [14864] dbg: pyzor: network tests on, attempting Pyzor
Oct  6 19:34:10.940 [14864] dbg: pyzor: pyzor is available: /bin/pyzor
Oct  6 19:34:10.942 [14864] dbg: pyzor: opening pipe: /bin/pyzor --homedir /some/dir/.pyzor check < /tmp/.spamassassin14864qX2Rmwtmp
Oct  6 19:34:11.248 [14864] dbg: pyzor: [14866] finished: exit 1
Oct  6 19:34:11.248 [14864] dbg: pyzor: got response: public.pyzor.org:24441 (200, 'OK') 0 0
...
```

---

In the same output, you should [see razor entry](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/RazorHowToTell) as well. In my server the output is

```
...
Jun  3 16:00:13.133 [12436] dbg: razor2: results: spam? 0
Jun  3 16:00:13.133 [12436] dbg: razor2: results: engine 8, highest cf score: 0
Jun  3 16:00:13.134 [12436] dbg: razor2: results: engine 4, highest cf score: 0
...
```